# Check if function is the same type as my typedef function in C?

Tags: c, types, function-pointers

I have the following code:

```
typedef int state_requester(void* request_paramaters);

int doSomething(state_requester* requester) {

    // This if statement is what I'm trying to
    // figure out how to do.

    if (requester isoftype state_requester) {
        requester(NULL);
        return 1;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to verify that the 
argument passed is actually a valid `state_requester`
function format before trying to execute it.

This code above is only ment as an example, and clearly isn't how things would really work. I just need to know how to do `if ( x isoftype y )` in regards to function typedefs.

Comment: C doesn't have this capability. Types are checked in compile time

Comment: BTW, `requester` is not type  `state_requester`.   `requester` is type  `state_requester *`.

Comment: ... but on the other hand, types *are* checked at compile time.  Such checks can be willfully overridden or their results can be ignored, but it's not like someone calling your function can accidentally pass an argument of the wrong type without any opportunity to discover their error.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can imagine a scenario where this function is called with some dynamically calculated pointers. The question is whether the op is meaning to have such a scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there's no real way to directly verify that the data is of a specific type, I've put together a way to 'presume' that the type matches.

*This does not 100% guarantee that it will be of the type specified.  However, it will presume that it is based on the type code.*

I've also added a few tests to it. I wrote this in a few minutes, so I'm sure that there is room for improvement in it, and I'm by no means a native developer. I just had a need and wrote it. If it helps someone, awesome!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Type Definitions

// These are the type definitions that can be used to check for type
// They need to be unique so that only types starting with these
// prefixes will be presumed to be of the type specified.
typedef enum type {
    TYPE_StateRequester = 0x10f3ccd3,
    TYPE_OtherThing = 0x09331c8c
} type;


// State Requester Definitions & Functions

typedef int state_requester_f(void* request_parameters);

// Since we want to check the "type" of a function reference,
// we need to wrap it in a struct along with it's type code.
struct state_requester_t {
    int type;
    state_requester_f* call;
} typedef state_requester_t;

state_requester_t new_state_requester(state_requester_f* call) {
    state_requester_t sr;
    sr.type = TYPE_StateRequester;
    sr.call = call;
    return sr;
}

// This function will check if data is of type StateRequester
// 
// If the data sent to this function is not of the length
// nessecary for the state_requester type, - OR - 
// it's type property is not equal to the StateRequester type
// then we will presume that this data is NOT of type StateRequester
uint8_t is_state_requester(void* data, size_t len) {
    return len == sizeof(state_requester_t) && 
           ((state_requester_t*)data)->type == TYPE_StateRequester;
}


// Testing functions

int test_caller(void* data) {
    printf("Got to the test_caller function.\n");

    return 0;
}

int main(int agc, char *argv[]) {

    // Create an actual state_requester_t definitiion
    state_requester_t sr = new_state_requester(&test_caller);

    // Test to see if it's validated as a state_requester_t
    if (is_state_requester(&sr, sizeof(state_requester_t))) {
        printf("Yes, variable 'sr' is presumadely of type state_requester_t\n");
        sr.call(NULL);
    } else {
        printf("No, variable 'sr' is not of type state_requester_t\n");
    }

    // Create a phony state_requester_t definition,
    // but keep it the same length as a regular
    // state_requester_t
    void* a = malloc(sizeof(state_requester_t));

    // Test to see if it's validated as a state_requester_t
    if (is_state_requester(a, sizeof(state_requester_t))) {
        printf("Yes, variable 'a' is presumadely of type state_requester_t\n");
    } else {
        printf("No, variable 'a' is not of type state_requester_t\n");
    }

    free(a);

    // Create a phony state_requester_t with an improper length
    void* b = malloc(5);

    // Test to see if it's validated as a state_requester_t 
    if (is_state_requester(b, sizeof(state_requester_t))) {
        printf("Yes, variable 'b' is presumadely of type state_requester_t\n");
    } else {
        printf("No, variable 'b' is not of type state_requester_t\n");
    }    

    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in C.

Types are checked in compile time, not runtime.

Note: `requester` is type `state_requester*`, and not `state_requester`.